# References title centered using apacite package

Tags: apacite

I am trying to get the reference's title centered using the `apacite package`.

Here is my MWE. I have tried using `\renewcommand{\refname}{\centering References}` but does not center the references' title.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\centering References}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={MidnightBlue},
    citecolor={MidnightBlue},
    urlcolor={MidnightBlue}
}

\usepackage{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\begin{document}
\title{A Title}
\date{\vspace{-10ex}}

\maketitle  
\section{Theoretical Framework}
\nocite{*}

\begingroup
\raggedright
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{main}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

And my `main.bib` contains:

```
@incollection{portes1989,
    author      = {Portes, Alejandro and Castells, Manuel}, 
    title       = {World underneath: The origins, dynamics, and effects of the informal economy},
    editor      = {Portes, Alejandro and Castells, Manuel and Benton, Lauren},
    booktitle   = {The Informal Economy: Studies in Advanced and Less Developed Countries},
    publisher   = {Johns Hopkins University Press},
    address     = {Baltimore, MD},
    year        = {1989},
    pages       = {11--37},
    chapter     = 1,
}


@article{hart1973,
    title       ={Informal income opportunities and urban employment in Ghana},
    author      ={Hart, Keith},
    journal     ={The Journal of Modern African Studies},
    volume      ={11},
    number      ={1},
    pages       ={61--89},
    year        ={1973},
    publisher   ={Cambridge Univ Press}
}

@article{tokman1978,
    title       = {An exploration into the nature of informal—formal sector relationships},
    journal     = {World Development},
    volume      = {6},
    number      = {9},
    pages       = {1065--1075},
    year        = {1978},
    issn        = {0305-750X},
    doi         = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0305-750X(78)90063-3},
    author      = {Victor E. Tokman},   
}

@article{harris1970,
    title       ={Migration, Unemployment and Development: A Two-Sector Analysis},
    author      ={Harris, John and Todaro, Michael},
    journal     ={American Economic Review},
    volume      ={60},
    number      ={1},
    pages       ={126--142},
    year        ={1970},
}

@book{de2002,
    title       ={The Other Path: The Economic Answer to Terrorism},
    author      ={de Soto, Hernando},
    isbn        ={9780465016105},
    year        ={1989},
    publisher   ={HarperCollins},
    address     ={New York},
}

@article{moser1978informal,
    title       ={Informal sector or petty commodity production: dualism or dependence in urban development?},
    author      ={Moser, Caroline},
    journal     ={World Development},
    volume      ={6},
    number      ={9-10},
    pages       ={1041--1064},
    year        ={1978},
    publisher   ={Elsevier},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it  with the `\titleformat*` command from `titlesec`, just before inserting your bibliography:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\centering References}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={MidnightBlue},
    citecolor={MidnightBlue},
    urlcolor={MidnightBlue}
}

\usepackage{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{\textsc{\Large The Political Economy of Informal Workers in Nicaragua}} \\ \normalsize Rony Rodriguez | Theory and Practice of Political Economy}
\date{\vspace{-10ex}}

\maketitle
\section{Theoretical Framework}
The concept of the informal economy was formally originated with the study of \citeA{hart1973} on the urban employment in Ghana. This study divided the exacerbated interest that, in the early 60s, was given to unemployment; and he redirected it towards the study of employment opportunities considered informal. Despite not presenting a clear definition of informal work, his study revealed the existence of a duality in the labor market, where part of the urban workforce was engaged in subsistence activities or ``new income-generating activities.” From this first approximation, different scholars proposed different approaches under which the informal economy can be understood.

Therefore, it is possible to categorize the study of the informal sector in four approaches. First, the dual approach that has been adopted by most of the international organizations as the International Labour Organization and The World Bank \cite{hart1973, harris1970, tokman1978}. Second, the regulationist approach which emphasizes the cost of being in the formal sector \cite{de2002}. Third, the structuralist approach that sees the informal sector as a subordinated economic units that are products of the economic structure \cite{portes1989, moser1978informal}. Finally, the voluntarist approach that focuses on the entrepreneurs as active actors within the informal sector.

\begingroup
\raggedright
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\Large\centering}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{main}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that it was that easy. @Bernard